# Is it possible to give bounty on meta?

Tags: support, bounty, meta, meta-reputation

Is there any trick to give bounty on this site? I have enough reputation on math.stackexchange.com and I would like give more than 10 or 25 points to the answerers in this topic: [Why Unsung Hero badge is so easy to obtain here?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18704/why-unsung-hero-badge-is-so-easy-to-obtain-here)

Comment: There is no reputation on meta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible. You may want to support the feature request [Bounty-like feature on metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231215/).

See also: [How to get attention to a post on a child meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188814/).

Comment: And making copy of meta-site question on the main site is rather against the rules? (It is near Christmas time. A good time for gifts).

Comment: It would be off-topic there.