# Bounties to reward not answers, but questions

Tags: discussion, bounty

MSE allows users to offer bounties to reward great *answers*, but the only mechanism in place to reward great *questions* is upvotes. Do you think questions should also be rewardable with bounties too?

I saw [this bounty question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234591/how-prove-this-geometry-inequality-r-14r-24r-34r-44r-54-geq-4-over-5) this morning. What impressed me is not the problem itself, but how the asker presented his/her failed efforts to tackle it. Most of us complain that many users just copy their homework problems from textbooks verbatim, without showing even any slight *intent* (not to mention *effort*) to solve the problems on their own. Some users did show their works, but to be honest, some of their works are so messy that I think a plain "please do my homework" question is even better.

At any rate, we almost never tell those users any good example of a question where the asker's efforts are well presented.

If questions are rewardable with bounties, bounty offerers can leave their reasons for the bounties in comments, and we can tell the others that "look, in this question, the asker's effort to solve the problem is so well presented that someone had even shown their appreciation by rewarding the question with bounty!"

Comment: Feature request on meta.SE: [Bounty-like facility for rewarding excellent questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135469/bounty-like-facility-for-rewarding-excellent-questions)

Comment: @MartinSleziak The discussion over there is very thorough. Thanks for the link.

Comment: A lot of people have briefly thought about it. It sounds like a great idea at first and then it doesn't.

Comment: In an ideal world, this would be an excellent idea. But realistically, I think it would only have negative consequences for all involved.

Comment: @RobertSoupe Yes, there may be some drawbacks, but *only* negative consequences? Why? Anyway, users of MSE at large are quite parsimonious about giving bounties. Whether or not there're merits or drawbacks, the impact should be incremental. If you go through the thread that Martin Sleziak linked to in his previous comment, you'll see some good reasons that go against this "bounty for question" thing, but there are good uses for it too (e.g. in Puzzling). I think whether the idea is a good one is really case/site dependent.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Say, you don't happen to know a "bounty for meta" type of thing?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt [Is it possible to give bounty on meta?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18805)

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak

Comment: For what it's worth, I stand by what I said in 2015.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, if someone places a regular bounty on my question, I'd be very pleased, and that in itself is the true joy of earning bounties as well (at least for me).

Not to mention, questions with bounties obviously get more views and upvotes in general, so there goes the bonus rep you wanted to award them.